# Determine the number of trials and variations of an MDP for analysis

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Given a simple grid world problem, if asked to compare and analyze several algorithms, it makes sense to run multiple trials due to stochasticity.  Does it also make sense to vary the *state* of the MDP in question, or does that make it a different MDP?

This is a question about definitions.  If I change the size of the grid in a grid world, the location of terminal states, or any other environment attribute, ***is it still the same MDP?*** And is there any reason to expect a solution to an MDP to generalize to another configuration of the same problem? In other words, will the Q-learner, for example, generalize to solving a finite grid world different from the one it solved? Do a typical separation of training and testing phases make sense when evaluating MDPs?  Is the only variation the stochasticity in state transitions?

Comment: Welcome here. I see a multitude of questions here. Which one is the key question? If you change the grid world, you change the number of states, you change the MDP. If you compare two things that are subject to stochasticity, you can use statistical tests such as z-test or Kolmogorov-Smirnov test.

Comment: That makes sense, and I realized it later.  An MDP solution would apply to a single map and wouldn't generalize to others.  My underlying question was really "does Q-Learning actually *learn* in the machine learning sense?".  I'm going to go back and study it a bit more.  Thank you.

Comment: Q-learning does learn the Q function. Even people learn the Q function when a student rejects a great night in a pub with friends, considering the exam the following day.

Comment: How do I mark your responses as "accepted" or helpful?  This was enough to get me going in the right direction.

Comment: Feel free to accept & upvote the answer.

Comment: Accepted! I don't have the reputation to upvote yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question contains several topics:

- How to compare strategies subject to stochasticity (stochastic strategy, stochastic environment): Each epoch can be perceived as a random experiment. For two strategies, you can consider standard statistical tests such as Kolmogorov-Smirnov.
- Does the MDP change if grid world changes: yes, MDP is defined on a given set of states. A different grid changes the states, at least.
- Is Q learning a form of machine learning: yes, the intelligent system learns how to decide in the long term, even sacrificing short-term rewards. On top of that, the learning uses the architectures that are standard for supervised machine learning such as Convolutional Neural Networks.